# AWSWrangler dataframe conversion to spark DF

Tags: pyspark, wrangler

I'm trying to convert a dataframe created by awswrangler to spark DF though not finding any resources? Please help

Tried using to_spark_dataframe

Code:
wr.s3.to_csv(df,"s3://bucket/out/aflogs.csv")

#Create PySpark DataFrame from Pandas
raw_df = df.to_spark_dataframe()

Error:
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_spark_dataframe'